# DataTable() - hide all rows where multiple colums match a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I Currently have a DataTable() uhm table that is filterable base upon a select box.

I have 3 columns of interest 5,6,7 and with this particular filter I want to do 2 things.

1. Only show rows where columns 6 & 7 equal exactly "0", "0"
2. Hide all rows where columns 5, 6 & 7  all equal exactly "0", "0", "0"

So in essence all remaining rows will contain: !="0", "0", "0", all the other permutations hidden.

Now I have this working for part 1, namely :

```
$('.dataTable').DataTable().column(5).search('', false, false, false).draw();
$('.dataTable').DataTable().column(6).search('^0$', true, false, false).draw();
$('.dataTable').DataTable().column(7).search('^0$', true, false, false).draw();
```

But I am completely stumped for part 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured a work-around, so it may not work in 100% f cases for anyone else that finds themselves in this same situation, depending on circumstances, but for my predicament it solved the issue.

Essentially I instead calculate which of 3 categories(a, b, c) the row falls within, in PHP, at the point where the table is generated. Add this to a data-search="" tag on the row, and then search on that.

```
<select name="type" id="type">
    <option value='' selected>All Types</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>

//... 

foreach($pos as $po) {
//...
    if($po['one'] == $po['two'] && $po['two'] == $po['three'] && $po['three'] == 0)
        $po_type = 'b';
    elseif($pov['one'] == 0)
        $po_type = 'b';
    else
        $po_type = 'a';
    <td data-search="<?php echo $po_type; ?>"><?php echo $po['one']; ?></td> // column 5, relevant in JavaScript
//...
}

//...

$('#type').change(function(){
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    $('.dataTable').DataTable().column(5).search('', false, false, false);
    $('.dataTable').DataTable().column(5).search($(this).val(), false, false, false).draw();
  }
  else {
    $('.dataTable').DataTable().column(5).search('', false, false, false);
  }
});
```

This works because the data-search attribute overrides the cell value when a search is performed against said cell, which when combined with moving the logic to PHP at the point of generating the table, circumvents the need for more complex combined & regex searches as in OP.

Nonetheless a DataTable ended solution would be both interesting and helpfull for similar sitations where this may not be feasible.